# Why is it that what I set in localStorage isn't the same as what I get?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, backbone.js, local-storage

Consider this code:

```
myObj = new BackboneModel({'a_key': {'c_key': c_val, 'd_key': d_val}, 'b_key': b_value});
localStorage.setItem('myObj', myObj);
```

Now if I use Chrome developer tools to inspect the data I get this:

```
> myObj
r {cid: "c1", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
> localStorage
Storage {myObj: "[object Object]"}
> myObj.get('a_key')
Object {c_key: Object, d_key: Object}
> localStorage.getItem('myObj')
"[object Object]"
```

I.e.) I don't get what I set...

Am I using localStorage incorrectly?

How can I get what I set?

NB: I assume that the details of my backbone.js model is irrelevant here.

**SOLVED**

```
// Set
var objDict = {'a_key': {'c_key': c_val, 'd_key': d_val}, 'b_key': b_value};
myObj = new BackboneModel(objDict);
localStorage.setItem('myObj', objDict);
...
// Get
var objDict = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObj'));
myObj = new BackboneModel(objDict);
```

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings, so your object gets converted to its `.toString()` value, which is `"[object Object]"`. It's the same sort of thing that happens when you `alert(myObj);`. You need to serialize your object to store it. `JSON` is often suitable for this, depending on the nature of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localStorage` can only directly store strings, and not objects - if you attempt to store an object it will call `.toString()` on that object, hence `[object Object]`.

Normally, I would suggest you using `JSON.stringify` when inserting objects, and `JSON.parse` when retrieving them.

However, you should note that going via JSON (or any other intermediate format) will not preserve any methods or prototype chains associated with that object.  The object you get back will have the same *contents* as your model, but it won't *be* a `BackboneModel`.

Comment: Thanks, I recreated the Backbone model using the retrieved JSON.

Comment: @MdaG great - I figured there'd be a way to recreate the model, but not being a Backbone user myself I didn't know what it was.

Comment: It was pretty simple after I understood the whole .toString(). I added the solution to my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MdaG right - the potential down side being that what you're storing is the model contents _before_ they were converted to a model, rather than the model itself (with its extra properties).

Comment: So you're saying that recreating the model might not yield the same result as when storing the data? What are my options?

Comment: @MdaG it depends - if Backbone just uses the object you've passed (such that changes in the model happen in the original too) you would be fine.  If it clones it, so that changes in the model don't change the original then serialising `objDict` might save an out-of-date copy of your data.  I believe there's a Backbone method (`toJSON`?) which will give you an object containing just the current values of the model attributes, and not the rest of the Backbone state.